# http PUT request with http-enumerator

Tags: haskell

I would like to use the http-enumerator package to perform not only GET/POST but also PUT.

http-enumerator:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-enumerator
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-enumerator/0.6.5/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Enumerator.html

*) my first step was to construct a Request and print it.
However I failed to write a proper Show function (error "No instance for Show .. arising from a use of print").

*) next I think I have to use the function "httpLbs :: MonadIO m => Request m -> Manager -> m Response" to get the Response.

for people who search and need that info too: haskell, REST or restful request, http, rest api access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http-enumerator/http-conduit doesn't really care if you're using POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. You just need to change the `method` record of the `Request` datatype. Your best bet is to rely on OverloadedStrings for this, something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Enumerator

main = do
    req <- parseUrl "http://www.example.com/put-url"
    withManager $ httpLbs req { method = "PUT" }
```

HTH

Comment: thanks a lot! just what I was looking for. maybe you could add it as an example somewhere in the docs.